# Why is my AWS Lambda Java function returning 'Hello World'?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm following this tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-step4-optional.html

and have pasted the code verbatim into my Java file:

```
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context; 
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;

public class Hello {
    public String myHandler(int myCount, Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("received : " + myCount);
        return String.valueOf(myCount);
    }
}
```

I then uploaded as a .zip file to S3, and used the 'Upload a file from Amazon S3' option.

My handler is:

```
example.Hello::myHandler
```

When I run my `Lambda`, I get:

[image]

Where is this coming from?

Comment: have you tested your java function locally? what value does it return? What was the test case you used for that case?

Comment: Did you reuse a Lambda that was configured for another language?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that is actually deployed to AWS?

Comment: This happens if you create a Java Lambda function from the hello world blueprint, then you update the function code to your own, but you neglect to deploy the changes to the Lambda function. Typically this only happens when using the AWS Lambda console, so not clear it's the cause here but sharing in case it's helpful.